# Ant Design Table with vertical and horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant Design Table to show dynamic data from an internal API here in the company.

This means that I don't know what kind of data I will receive to fill each cell. It can be a large text, a number, an empty value, a short string, image, url, anything.

I need to apply horizontal and vertical scroll, but as described on Ant Design docs:

> Specify the width of columns if header and cell do not align properly. (Leave one column at least without width to fit fluid layout) A fixed value which is greater than table width for scroll.x is recommended. The sum of unfixed columns should not greater than scroll.x.

Right now, the width is fine, Ant Design Table could figure out the best proportion for each column. See the image bellow:

[image: Without setting height for the table]

The problem is when I set the y scroll. Bellow an example:

[image: Setting height the table]

The major issue here is that I don't know the size of the data for each column.
Speaking of columns, I have to extract the **key** from the table source in order to generate the columns dynamically.

Is it possible to go around this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this case done already?

Comment: @OnesinusSaut no.

Comment: @spiny_beast I did a workaround to fix this. It's not the most charming solution, but I ran into every column calculating their width based on the number of chars. I also set a maximum value for each column width. It worked. Just pay attention to the amount of data in your table, it might cause some problems with performance. You can also set a pagination to help you with the performance =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came up with a workaround for my problem. In order to set a width for the entire table based on the width of my columns, I had to go through all the table data calculating each cell width based on the length of its own content.

After that, I can sum the total width and set it to the table.

Here an example using this approach:

[image: Edit wonderful-tree-ukyy5]

Answer (score 23):

So this is a known issue at Ant Design check [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/15794), [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/14904), [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/7603) and [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/7931)

there is not a proper fix, I faced the same issue, I tried setting the width for each column, Set "width" property in the column works, but it breaks for sticky header.

another simple way around to this is using horizontal scroll and removing vertical scroll somewhat like this

```
scroll={{ x: 400 }}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did the same as you, I set the width for each column, but I did that dynamically and it worked. Now you can set XScroll, YScroll and fixed columns. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 14):

Refer to [this comment](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/15794#issuecomment-768782351) in the issue attached by @Afaq.

> For anyone having this issue, set a width for each of your columns and in the Table, add the following code: scroll={{ x: "max-content" }}. This will adjust your column width automatically.

This should solve for most people.

Comment: thanks karan! just using max-content on table worked for me, I didn't have to set the width for each column separately.